# is bootstrap 3 automatically responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that `Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.` So it helps makes the websites responsive and stuff. Currently, I have another file for `css` where I use `media queries` and re organize my css layout through that (thats how I make it responsive).

Does Bootstrap handle all media queries for me, or will I need to do additional legwork?

Comment: I'm sorry, but such question doesn't provide any pratical or specific problem but rather a vague one. Besides, such is not necessarely related to jQuery and javascript, since you are asking more about media queries. If the true question is: **do I need to take care of media queries?** the answer is **no, as long as you're using the tools that boostrap is giving you**. In any case, bootstrap **won't do any magic for your existing project**, you will need to use its grid system and use the components it gives you.

Comment: Yes I was generally asking about mediaquerries

Comment: It's not going to automatically make your _existing_ layout responsive, you'll need to use Bootstrap's grid system by using the relevant class names.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, all media queries are handled by bootstrap. You just need to assign the appropriate classes to your html elements.

More information on the grid system can be found here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You'll have to modify your html won't have to make any additional css modifications for bootstrap to work 'out of the box'

Bootstrap uses four devices sizes: XS, XM, MD, and LG. Here are the media queries that bootstrap uses. You may want to compare so that you can make sure your system is close to theres. Otherwise you may need to do a larger overhaul.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: Boostrap does not _handle_ all media queries, it _provides_ a common set of classes, _component_ that are styled differently according to a set of _predefined_ media queries. Most values related to sizes (e.g. `screen-md-min`) can be customized using a config file and a sass or less preprocessor to fit the requirments of the project. It is not uncommon to add own mediaqueries with own values or with the one of the config file to add components, that are not included in bootstrap.

Comment: I would beg to differ. Bootstrap's predefined media queries handle all device sizes. You CAN add your own media queries, but you do not need to. Because bootstrap handles all media queries.

Comment: For a backend or web application you might be able to just use the classes and components that are provided by bootstrap, but it is still more likely that you need to create own components where you have to define media queries so that the are responsive. For good looking webpages there is normally no way around to defined own media queries based on the ones provided by bootstrap.

Comment: I believe thats an over generalization, but if that's your experience with it, thats fine. In my own experience, I've only had to use very limited use of media queries in conjunction with bootstrap.